# What did George Lucas sue Battlestar Galactica for?

Tags: star-wars, battlestar-galactica, george-lucas

I can't think of anything similar in the franchises beyond "bad guys wear black." There was no supernatural power (that I recall), no elite superheroes. Heck, there was no hyperdrive!

Does anyone know what George Lucas thought was stolen from Star Wars?

Comment: https://uk.news.yahoo.com/40-years-ago-battlestar-galactica-debuted-george-lucas-sued-134856528.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAALTns_O6azOjdeao08YzyqcfSN1VMOXUd06P-T7yTuHQ6RsLcxApeiPeszxCqglksx5HgnkEscVPYSbjAedokDquPZSMRvaNEMPrZP3wIrkPySSCyfg5V6H5CALzSAr5Wh7ywy5hCX-05eraALKtjNBUWiIsHBRvSFwsmy17DM-_

Comment: https://www.upi.com/Archives/1983/01/11/Star-Wars-can-sue-Battlestar-Galactica-in-copyright-dispute/9774411109200/

Comment: https://ut.lawstudentland.com/post/112081931892/star-wars-v-battlestar-galactic-saga-of-a-fact

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the [legal case](https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/appellate-courts/F2/715/1327/405049/) (based on Lucas' acquisition of a 1978 script for Battlestar Galactica)

> Appellant Fox argued in its brief that a comparison of the two works discloses at least 34 similarities. For illustrative purposes only, we list 13 of the alleged similarities:
>
> (1) The central conflict of each story is a war between the galaxy's democratic and totalitarian forces.
>
> (2) In Star Wars the young hero's father had been a leader of the democratic forces, and the present leader of the democratic forces is a father figure to the young hero. In Battlestar the young hero's father is a leader of the democratic forces.
>
> (3) The leader of the democratic forces is an older man, displaying great wisdom, and symbolizing goodness and leadership, with a mysterious mystical ability to dominate a leader of the totalitarian forces.
>
> (4) An entire planet, central to the existence of the democratic forces, is destroyed.
>
> (5) The heroine is imprisoned by the totalitarian forces.
>
> (6) A leading character returns to the family home to find it destroyed.
>
> (7) The search by the totalitarians and the liberation attempt by the democratic forces are depicted in alternating sequences between the totalitarian and democratic camps.
>
> (8) There is a romance between the hero's friend (the cynical fighter pilot) and the daughter of one of the leaders of the democratic forces.
>
> (9) A friendly robot, who aids the democratic forces is severely injured (Star Wars) or destroyed (Battlestar) by the totalitarian forces.
>
> (10) There is a scene in a cantina (Star Wars) or casino (Battlestar), in which musical entertainment is offered by bizarre, non-human creatures.
>
> (11) Space vehicles, although futuristic, are made to look used and old, contrary to the stereo-typical sleek, new appearance of space age equipment.
>
> (12) The climax consists of an attack by the democratic fighter pilots on the totalitarian headquarters.
>
> (13) Each work ends with an awards ceremony in honor of the democratic heros.

etc.

Ultimately the script was re-worked and the case was dropped with both sides accepting their own legal liability. This gentleman's agreement seems to have been contingent on Lucasfilm's *Industrial Light and Magic* providing the special effects for the Galactica pilot and series.

Comment: Plot lines? Darn good thing Flash Gordon didn't sue Lucas! Ming=Vader, Evil Planet=Death Star, etc...

Comment: On the face of it, it does seem very similar. Sufficiently so that the 9th Circuit referred it for a jury trial. In the end it never made it there, presumably because both sides weren't sure that they'd win

Comment: "In Star Wars the young hero's father had been a leader of the democratic forces, and the present leader of the democratic forces is a father figure to the young hero"

I'm confused. Was the case claiming that Obi-wan was a leader for the Rebellion? Cause that seems to be a bit of a stretch. Great answer tho

Comment: @DariM - I think the implication is that in the original BSG script (originally known as "Battle for the Stars"(!), Adama was more of an Obi-Wan like mentor figure

Comment: Everyone should be sued by Joseph Campbell ...

Comment: ...and every writer of myths and fairy tales should sue Joseph Campbell.  :-)

Comment: Damn.  If they're that loose about the facts, I can find 13 ways *Love, Actually* did the same thing...

Comment: @Harper - There were another 20+ of these. Taken singly, you could argue that these are tropes that many/most films use. When there's 35+ of them, it starts to look a lot like the writer was at least *strongly influenced* by watching the film or reading the other film's script.